# Phaser 3 this.scene undefined inside callback

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am trying to create a game with Phaser 3. I want to change the scene when the boss is dead, but when I pass the scene to a callback I got undefined. The scene is there inside the function before the callback. How can I fix it?

My code is:

```
export default class Boss extends Entity {
  constructor(scene) {
    super(scene, 400, 80, "boss", "Boss");
    this.scene = scene;
    this.play("boss");
    this.lifes = 15;
    
    this.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    
    this.shootTimer = this.scene.time.addEvent({
      delay: 1000,
      callback: function() {
        this.body.velocity.x = Phaser.Math.Between(-200, 200);
        var missile = new EnemyMissile(
          this.scene,
          this.x,
          this.y
        );
        var missile2 = new EnemyMissile(
          this.scene,
          this.x + 25,
          this.y + 25
        );
        var missile3 = new EnemyMissile(
          this.scene,
          this.x - 25,
          this.y - 25
        );
        missile.setScale(this.scaleX);
        this.scene.enemyMissiles.add(missile);
        missile2.setScale(this.scaleX);
        this.scene.enemyMissiles.add(missile2);
        missile3.setScale(this.scaleX);
        this.scene.enemyMissiles.add(missile3);
      },
      callbackScope: this,
      loop: true
    });
  }
  
  onDestroy() {
    console.log(this.scene);   //here I got the scene
    this.scene.time.addEvent({ 
      delay: 1000,
      callback: function() {        
        this.scene.scene.start('EndGame'); // here this.scene is undefined
      },
      callbackScope: this,
      loop: false
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use fat arrow function to get parent context & you have putted `this.scene.scene.start('EndGame');` in wrong way, this should be `this.scene.start('EndGame');`. Change your code like this:

```
onDestroy() {
    console.log(this.scene);   //here I got the scene
    this.scene.time.addEvent({ 
        delay: 1000,
        callback: () => {        
            this.scene.start('EndGame'); // this.scene is defined here
        },
        callbackScope: this,
        loop: false
    });
}
```

Comment: Still undefined! I copied your full cde and it is not working! My code is working when the player is dead! But I do not know why is not working with the boss class!